# Change tkinter background from different functions in different modules

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, tkinter

Is there a way i can change the background color of tkinter from different modules?

For example lets say Simpletoggle runs.
within Simpletoggle
there is a another function that gets called, this function from the different file should change the color of the background.

The idea is to have colour effect when a different function is called.

Thank you

First module

```
def Simpletoggle():
    data()
      
 

ws = Tk()
ws.title("Python Guides")
app_picture = Label (ws,image=filename)
toggle_button = Button(text="Active", width=10, command=Simpletoggle)
ws.configure(bg='red')
ws.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a really simple example where the function to change button colour is taken from another file, in this case `Seconday`, and used in `simpletoggle` to configure whatever widget is assigned as an input, in this case the root window, `ws`.

Main.py

```
from tkinter import *
from Secondary import update_colour

ws = Tk()
ws.title("Python Guides")


def simpletoggle():
    # data()
    update_colour(ws)


app_picture = Label(ws)
app_picture.grid(column=0, row=0)

toggle_button = Button(ws, text="Active", command=simpletoggle)
toggle_button.grid(column=0, row=0)

ws.configure(bg='red')


ws.mainloop()
```

Secondary.py

```
def update_colour(widget):
    widget.configure(bg='green')
```

Comment: thank you! Will i have to repeat what has been done in secondary.py for other modules?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean without knowing what specifically you are trying to do with your other tkinter widgets. If its just changing colour you could just use `update_colour` and change the widget input. I'd advocate formatting tkinter using a class structure though, as it can make passing variables and accessing tkinter widgets far easier. [Heres a link on tkinter classes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17470842/12282048), and a [really helpful response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70614538/12282048) to a question I asked recently about accessing variables & widgets in other classes.